# Material Chip the selection behavior doesn't work

Tags: android, android-chips

I can't understand how the Chip works. I want to do a a view which contains dynamic filters to select. When I select a chip, there is a press effect (OK), but the chip doesn't stay in the selected state...

I did this quick example in XML. The result is the same...

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
        android:id="@+id/tags"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/keyline_0"
        app:chipSpacingHorizontal="8dp"
        app:lineSpacing="8dp">

        <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
            android:id="@+id/chip"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="test"/>

        <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
            android:id="@+id/chip2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="test2"/>

        <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
            android:id="@+id/chip3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="test3"/>

        <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
            android:id="@+id/chip4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="test4"/>

    </com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>
```

[image]

Comment: Please check this link about [filter chip](https://material.io/components/chips/android#filter-chip), you need to change `style` of your chip

Answer (score 0):

To style a chip view you need to apply `@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice` style to the `Chip` element. (It is not for `ChipGroup`).

Take a look at https://material.io/components/chips/android#choice-chip,

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
    chips.isCheckable = true
```

and then set this

```
    chips.setOnCheckedChangeListener { compoundButton, b ->
              
    }
```